# Trying To Implement Concurrent TCP Server and Client in c

Tags: c, sockets, concurrency, tcp

I have implemented TCp concurrent server and client in c using threads as well as forks.
But I don't have any way to check whether there is any other standard way of implementing 
this.

I have goggled for standard coding stuff but didnt find anything useful.
Can someone pl z share some good links or code so that I can have a standard idea of
implementing Concurrent servers.

Thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean by "Concurrent server"? Handling more than one client connection?

Comment: I answered something similar a few days ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267535/how-does-an-asynchronous-socket-server-work

Comment: @Brian : yeah the same...Also Full duplex communication between Client and Server...........

Comment: See also this answer to a question about event-driven webservers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981566/what-is-event-driven-web-server/3982440#3982440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "standard idea". Your approach is going to depend on requirements, performance, scalability, and amount of time allowed for development.

- One thread per client

  - Possibly with a threadpool
- Multi-threaded pipeline model, with N workers
- One thread per server, using poll/select
- One thread per server, event-based with callbacks
- Forking children, one per client connection

  - pre-forking children, e.g. Apache web server

Etc. All of these have their uses.

Answer (score 2):

Some good links for you:

- [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) will help you get the basics down,
- [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) will give you an overview of the design landscape,
- [High-Performance Server Architecture](http://pl.atyp.us/content/tech/servers.html) will make you re-think the "standard" approaches.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent servers (as long as they are quite simple, and performance is not much of an issue) are often created with [poll()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select). Now, this is assuming you are on *nix.
If you can use C++, the boost libraries have [ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html) , which is a cross-platform library that allows you to write once and compile everywhere. There isn't really a standard way to do things since the ideas vary from OS to OS.