# How are threads managed for Begin/Async calls (like socket IO)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

The .Net Socket async API manages threads automatically when using the `BeginXXX` methods. For example, if I have 100 active connections sending and receiving `TCP` messages, will be used around 3 threads. And it makes me curious.

- How the API makes this thread management?
- How all flow of connections are divided among the threads to be processed?
- How the manager prioritizes which connections/readings/writings must be processed first?

My questions may not have sense because I don't know how it works and what to ask specifically, so sorry. Basically I need to know how this whole process works in low level.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267535/how-does-an-asynchronous-socket-server-work)

Comment: Good question, but it seems to have been answered. (See @Tinwor 's comment).

Comment: @Tinwor, I disagree the linked question is a duplicate. It somewhat overlaps, but the answers do not explain how threads are allocated to serve the I/O completion and how they're returned to the pool, while that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The .Net Socket async API manages threads automatically when using the
>   BeginXXX methods.

This is not quite correct. APM `Begin/End`-style socket API do not manage threads at all. Rather, the completion `AsyncCallback` is called on a random thread, which is the thread where  the asynchronous socket I/O operation has completed. Most likely, this is going to be an IOCP pool thread (I/O completion port thread), different from the thread on which you called the `BeginXXX` method. For more details, check Stephen Cleary's ["There Is No Thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

> How the manager prioritizes which connections/readings/writings must
>   be processed first?

The case when there's no IOCP threads available to handle the completion of the async I/O operation is called `TheadPool` starvation. It happens when all pool threads are busy executing some code (e.g., processing the received socket messages), or are blocked with a blocking call like `WaitHandle.WaitOne()`. In this case, the I/O completion routine is queued to `ThreadPool` to be executed when a thread becomes available, on FIFO basis.

You have an option to increase the size of `ThreadPool` with `SetMinThreads/SetMaxThreads` APIs, but doing so isn't always a good idea. The number of actual concurrent threads is anyway limited by the number of CPU/cores, so you'd rather want to finish any CPU-bound processing work as soon as possible and release the thread to go back to the pool.